# Android studio Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am a beginner in android studio, i have started creating the app named Hello World but always in the gradle build tab, its shows 2 errors. The errors i face are:

> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'e:\Program Files\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} dependencies {}
```

What should i do now to run my program without errors, please help me........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" is declared in modul "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"

so you need something like this in your build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

alternativly you can use "Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" instead which is part of newer android versions and does not need an extra modul.

"Theme.AppCompat.xxx" and "com.android.support:appcompat-v7" was created to allow old android versions like android-2.2 to user newer features introduced in newer android versions.

Comment: Thank u @k3bBut there is a new problem which shows                        Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1